# This user is spamming completely irrelevant content in an answer.

Tags: discussion, moderators, specific-user, spam

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1932303/272831
- https://math.stackexchange.com/users/370219/bas-das

This user is posting random content from youtube videos that have nothing to do with math.  I wanted to report this here because I'm not entirely sure what much I can do about the situation and it is very annoying.

Comment: This sounds like spam. There's a flag for that.

Comment: Spam or otherwise, certainly flagging for moderator attention is an option.

Comment: Flagging will work. User destroyed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Nice, I see that they are dead now